# How do I find the mouse button properties tab when Windows 8 defaults to the "Mouse and Keyboard Center"?

Tags: windows-8, mouse

I am trying to switch my primary and secondary buttons on my mouse. This used to not be a problem for me. I would go to "change mouse settings" and click the "button" tab.

Now, however, I see a new dialog window that doesn't make sense to me that asks for the "Mouse and Keyboard Center." Clicking on this opens to a new window that says that my mouse is not supported.

Does anyone know how to get to this old button tab to fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Mouse and Keyboard Center compatibility list for Win8](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-ca/help/windows-8/troubleshooting/mouse/supported-devices) to see if your mouse is on there.

If it's an older MS mouse and it's not on the list, uninstall the Mouse and Keyboard Center, and use the [MS IntelliPoint software](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=26950) instead.

If it's not an MS mouse at all, uninstall the M&K Center and install the application(s) supplied by your mouse's manufacturer.

Comment: Uninstalling the Mouse and Keyboard Center worked! I have no idea where it came from, but now we're back to the old dialogue menu.